# How to detect rooted phone when the app is added in Deny List of Magisk >24

Tags: android, rooted-device

Is there any perfect method to identify phones rooted with Magisk(Version >24)? The traces of Magisk/Zygisk were found in /proc/self/mounts. But when the application is added to the 'Deny List' of Magisk, even these traces are removed. Most of the checks available on the internet are not working with Magisk >24.

Even for SafetyNet API, Magisk modules are available to bypass detection(Universal SafetyNet Fix). As they have provided an option to rename the app internally, identifying Magisk with the package name is also not working. I have tried most of the GitHub projects to detect Magisk(Magisk Detector, Magisk Killer, etc) and failed.  I have tried most of the Java Code, native C code, and Assembly Code available on the internet to check for magisk and failed

Is there any perfect way to detect Magisk >24?
Is there any

Comment: Just consider, if someone would post here a perfect way to detect Magisk, tomorrow Magisk would be patched. So what do you expect as answer?

Comment: I completely agree with you. Still, there are few applications like MOMO that detect Magisk even though it is added in DenyList.   I am curious to know how they detect Magisk/Zygisk

Comment: Have you found anything to detect this one?

Comment: no still working on it